# JqGrid tables reloading after editing and saving any row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jqgrid

I have 4 jqGrid tables in a php file and passsing different json array for the each grid tables.The data which i am displaying on grid are from 1 table with different sql conditions.

I am using inline editing functionality for all the grids and when i edit and save the row from table1, i want all the grids should get **refresh** so that if the row which was previously edited is exists in next tables that should get vanished automatically.
I want to **reload** the all the grid tables after editing any row in any table.
I have written the following code:

```
<table id="jqgrid"></table>
<div id="pjqgrid"></div>

<table id="jqgrid1"></table>
<div id="pjqgrid1"></div>

<table id="jqgrid2"></table>
<div id="pjqgrid2"></div>

<table id="jqgrid3"></table>
<div id="pjqgrid3"></div>

<script>
pageSetUp();
var myEditOptions = {
    keys: true,
    successfunc: function (response) {
       // alert(JSON.stringify(response)); 
        var msg=response.responseText;
        var n =msg.search("Updated");
        //alert(n);
        if(n>=0)
        {
            $(".inner").html("<div class='alert alert-success fade in'>     <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>X</button><i class='fa-fw fa fa-thumbs-up'></i>  "+msg+" </div>");
        } 
        else
        {
            $(".inner").html("<div class='alert alert-danger fade in'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>X</button><i class='fa-fw fa fa-thumbs-down'></i>  "+msg+" </div>");      
        }
        $("#jqgrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
        $("#jqgrid1").trigger('reloadGrid');
        $("#jqgrid2").trigger('reloadGrid');
        $("#jqgrid3").trigger('reloadGrid');
        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('resetSelection');
        jQuery("#jqgrid1").jqGrid('resetSelection');
        jQuery("#jqgrid2").jqGrid('resetSelection');
        jQuery("#jqgrid3").jqGrid('resetSelection');
        return true;     
    },
    errorfunc: function (rowid,response) {
        //alert(rowid);
    },
    afterrestorefunc:function (rowid,response) {
        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('resetSelection');
    }

};
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question? What problem you have currently?

Comment: after saving anyrow in any table i want to refresh all the grids so that the data which i am displaying in table should get refreshed.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a question. You posted already some code which calls `reloadGrid`. So you should describe what worked incorrect in your current code, what is expecting results and what you see instead. I posted my answer where I recommend you to use `aftersavefunc` callback instead of `successfunc` and to make reloading *after* finishing if editing of the row (one need to use `setTimeout`).

Comment: sure. thanks for your answer. i will use aftersavefunc and if everything is fine then i will accept your answer.

Comment: I mean not only my own answers. You received many answers of your previous questions. People spend his time, somebody created demo examples for you, but you ignored many from the answers. No answers was accepted and many answers was stay without your comments. Even writing of short "Thanks" in the comment could be good. If you want to receive answers on your new questions in the future you should be more polite with people who invest his private time and trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It would you recommend to use `aftersavefunc` instead of `successfunc` for reloading of the grids. Moreover you should place `.trigger("reloadGrid")` inside of `setTimeout`. It will allows *to finish processing of editing* before starting reloading:

```
var myEditOptions = {
    keys: true,
    aftersavefunc: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#jqgrid,#jqgrid1,#jqgrid2,#jqgrid3").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }, 50);
    },
    ...
};
```